# Free ad exchange framework for Android?

Tags: android

I know that Android has some ad networks to monetize the apps. But I'm looking for an ads systems that allows me to advertise for free on other apps/games, and at the same time I advertise them on mine.

In windows phone we have this: http://www.adduplex.com/

Is there something similar for Android?

Comment: Do you mean mixing different ad providers, like adwhirl?

Comment: please have a look at adduplex. It is not just ads, its FREE ads exchange, while you can keep buying ads and not to put banners on your own games/apps if you don't want to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if you are still looking for an answer to this, but I use http://www.appflood.com and http://www.tapfortap.com. I know there are some others, but so far appflood seems to have the best setup and is back by papaya.

Comment: Neither of those two websites exists (at least not any more as of June 2019)

Answer (score 0):

I was looking at similar solutions a few months ago. The short answer: no, there is no such thing for Android. The longer answer: you might find something, but the network will be too small to even bother trying the solution out. So the closest thing to your needs is [AdWhirl](https://www.adwhirl.com/). It does not let you promote your app in other apps. However, you can choose to try a number of large networks, such as AdMob, and - after some testing - stick to the one you get best results with. In addition to that, it allows you to show custom ads so that you can cross-promote your products. The tool is open source and, as a bonus, also works with iOS.

Other than that, you might consider choosing [AdMob](http://www.admob.com/) (or any other network), and spending the money you earn from ads in your app for promoting your app in other apps. While this is definitely more tedious than the AdDuplex solution, you also get some solid benefits: the ads in popular networks might be of higher quality (no spam and other crap), some networks also try to show ads that are more likely to interest the user (thus a higher click-through rate), you can clearly target users for your own ads (e.g., ads are shown based on location or a demographic feature of the user), and, besides just simple ads, your ads, can, for example, be click-to-download ads that lead to direct app downloads.

Comment: uf, then I'll have to implement adduplex for Android and get rich :-)

Comment: Not sure about how much potential it has. You might get richer by making great apps and using AdMob ;).

Comment: When you talk about benefits of selling ads in your apps and then buying other ads for your apps, you're forgetting that makes a leak of money into the middle-man.